# Change Ubuntu's boot image

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I have been trying to change Ubuntu's boot image that ugly magenta background image I have tried editing grub.cfg but it doesn't work?
What can I do to remove the default boot image on Ubuntu and replace it with a better image?

Answer (score 0):

The boot image/animation can be changed using plymouth

get a list of pre-built images for you

```
sudo apt list plymouth-theme*
```

then install

```
sudo apt install <name of package>
```

then run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

and select your new splash screen and then to finalize

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

then reboot

http://ubuntuguide.net/howto-change-plymouth-themes-initial-splash-screen-in-ubuntu-10-04

Comment: It doesn't work, I can still see that purple/magenta background every single time I reboot my ubuntu desktop

Comment: Were there any errors on when you ran those commands?

Comment: None everything responded and I keyed in what you advised but nothing changed.

Comment: What actually worked is using the Plymouth manager. Downloading a theme of my choice and importing a background image using boot manager